# Sorting distinct linq to entities result set

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am querying a table for distinct column entries:

```
var thing = (from i in db.Items
                     select i.GeoName).Distinct();
```

This works well.

However, it is unordered.

Is there an easy way to sort this resultset?

I tried

```
var thing = (from i in db.Items
                     orderby i.GeoName descending
                     select i.GeoName).Distinct();
```

Which does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Distinct()` is not an order-preserving operation, you'll need to perform the OrderBy *after* the call to `Distinct()`. The easiest way to do that is with lambda syntax:

```
var thing = (from i in db.Items
                 select i.GeoName)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(n => n);
```

Another way to say the same thing is:

```
var thing = db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName)
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(n => n);
```

Or, if you're dead-set on using query expression syntax:

```
var thing = from geoName in
                (from i in db.Items
                 select i.GeoName)
                .Distinct()
            orderby geoName
            select geoName;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that was not only quick, but excellently to the point. Thanks again!

Comment: @mrwienerdog: I updated my answer a few times within the first few minutes, and I think I made the change you're describing. Is there something I'm still missing?